# Angular Material can't set md-card as an anchor

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is it possible to make the whole card a link in Angular material or is there another directive intended for this use case?

Comment: Is it just enough to put an <a> around it or isn't this the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put a `ng-click` on the card and perform your operation.Further you can style the card with hover effects to get the feel of a link.Like this :

**HTML:**

```
<md-card ng-click="cardSelected()" class="cardAsLink">
      ....
</md-card>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.cardSelected=function(){
  console.log("card Clicked");
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.cardAsLink{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cardAsLink:hover{
  border : 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this answer is not good for accessibility, since it breaks most of the functionality of an anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can put an anchor tag around the card. I think it is the better solution because you have the hole functionality of the anchor tag. In Ramblers answer clicking would work fine and if you use the the router the historie would also be korrect, but thinks like clicking with the mouse wheel to open a new tap would not work. The same goes for right mouse click thinks and the navigation preview on the bottom of the browser would also be missing.